# Reset text output from R in spotfire

Tags: r, spotfire, terr

I have written a code to generate texts based on certain conditions in Spotfire using R. The code refreshes automatically whenever a selection is made. Since there are a lot of if-else condition used in R, the code takes a noticeable time to refresh the content. The dashboards change but the text changes after a lag.

Is there anyway to reset the text output while the R code runs so that the user doesn't get confused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've go some Python triggered data function that can take between 5 minutes to an hour to execute. The hardest part is getting the HTML of a text area to update. What I've currently implemented is a [loading bar coded by Halpenfield](https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-show-loading-prompt-when-reloading-external-data). Something I've been meaning to try but haven't gotten to yet is [a more descriptive popup](https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-add-progress-bar-and-cancellation-option-when-executing-ironpython-scripts-tibco-spotfire).

[image]

These won't reset the displayed text before executing code but they will make it clear to the user something is happening. There might be a way to do directly what you are asking with two HTML's and a forced refresh like Halpenfield uses.